# Extract text from a file object using .read()

Tags: python, urllib2, urlopen

I'm trying to read the source of a website with this code:

```
import urllib2
z=urllib2.urlopen('http://skreemr.com/results.jsp?q=said+the+whale&search=SkreemR+Search')
z.read()
print z
txt = open('music.txt','w')
txt.write(str(z))
txt.close()
for i in open('music.txt','r'):
        if '''onclick="javascript:pageTracker._trackPageview('/clicks/''' in i:
                print i
```

And all I get for the source code is:

```
<addinfourl at 51561608L whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x0000000002CCA480>>
```

It might be an error I don't know?
Does anyone know of a better way to do the job above without putting it into a text file first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`z` is a file object. In fact your codes prints the object description. You need to put the result of `z.read()` inside a variable (or print it directly).

You should do

```
import urllib2
z=urllib2.urlopen('http://skreemr.com/results.jsp?q=said+the+whale&search=SkreemR+Search')
i = z.read()
print i
```

Answer (score 2):

`.read()` does not actually change the state of `z`.  Use `z=z.read()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`z` is the file-like object. `str(z)` just gives you the representation you're seeing.

You need to keep the string (the contents of the file) that's returned by `z.read()`.

Better yet, just iterate over it directly:

```
import urllib2
z=urllib2.urlopen('http://skreemr.com/results.jsp?q=said+the+whale&search=SkreemR+Search')
for i in z:
    if '''onclick="javascript:pageTracker._trackPageview('/clicks/''' in i:
        print i
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing what `read` does. Try:

```
data = z.read()
print data
with open('music.txt','w') as txt:
    txt.write(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('music.txt','w') as out:
    out.write(urllib2.urlopen('http://skreemr.com/results.jsp?q=said+the+whale&search=SkreemR+Search').read()
```

But this is just the html for the page, you will need to parse it yourself using beautiful soup or lxml